# Win 8 / 10 - Slow internet unless using Safe Mode

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, safe-mode, broadband, wired-networking

I have a completely clean install of Windows 10 Pro 64bit (Installed and fully updated via Windows Update today), and when in Usermode I can see 46-47Mbit transfers (Speedtest.net, MS Iso downloads, Steam, www.thinkbroadband.com/download/ ) but when in Safemode with Networking I see 105MBit/s

(I also have a Win 8.1 machine exhibiting same, as well as a laptop, but let's focus on the desktop for now)

I have tried:

- 3 NICs (Onboard Intel, Onboard Realtek, PCIe Intel 1000)
- Windows Firewall on/off
- Windows Defender on/off
- Windows update disabled / P2P distribution off
- Windows telemetry disabled
- Telemetry hosts blocked
- Reserved Bandwidth QoS Policy set
- Duplex settings set to 1Gbs bidirectional
- Default windows-update NIC drivers / Latest NIC drivers from Intel
- Jumbo frames to Off/9k
- Large Send Offload  Enabled/Disabled

None of the above has made any difference.

Safemode: 105MBit/s
Normal Mode: 46-47MBit/s

Prior to the download test I checked the network utilisation to ensure it was 0. During the speed tests no processes spike the CPU other than the browser being used. I've tested downloads in Edge, IE11 and Opera 40.

Motherboard is an ASRock Extreme 6, with an Intel I218V NIC onboard. 32Gb RAM, i7 4790K with SSD drive. It is literally a virgin Windows 10 installation, with only Opera and mIRC installed, along obviously with device drivers.

Router is a Linksys WRT54g, however I'm not convinced that has anything to do with it as the Safemode speeds are fine.

I am aware others have asked this in 2014, but their threads were never resolved - I was unsure of the etiquette for reviving zombie threads on SU, forgive me if I should have simply replied to one of those :(

### Update

Removing the WRT54g from the loop gives me 105MBit/sec in Usermode. 
This means that something in Usermode is freaking out the WRT54g which doesn't happen in Safemode. Could be dynamic MTU, framesize, etc etc... but without Wiresharking it I won't know.

The solution for now may well be to just upgrade the venerable WRT54g, though I'd love to know exactly why Safemode behaves itself...

Comment: You've checked all the obvious things, and many non obvious. Using msconfig, try disabling startup on everything to create a default config close to safe mode with networking. Reboot and test your speed. Add a startup service / program; reboot and retest - iterate until you find the change that introduces the issue.

Comment: Do you know of any straightforward way of isolating which services are loaded in safemode by default? That would at least narrow it down.

Comment: Can you confirm that you've fiddled with the QoS Policy (reserve bandwidth option) and Unchecked "Download Updates from other machines" actually scratch that - I've just seen you have from the list above.

Comment: Yes - as stated in the original post :(

Comment: The best I can think of is looking at the boot log created in %SystemRoot% when you boot into safe mode which will list everything that got loaded. In safe mode you can also open task manager and view what services are running. I don't know of a definitive list though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try finding the setting(s) for full duplex on both end of the equipment.

Some switches try very hard to auto detect full duplex and if the cable is a cross over, but fail with certain brands of NIC and sometimes different versions of the drivers (across operating systems too). Cisco for example is a prime example.

I remember having a similar problem with my switch (some low end HP enterprise thing) and an Intel NIC on a linux server. It was very variable with its negotiation 10/100/FDX/HDX it was all over the place. You can imagine eventually the OS gave up and defaulted to 10MB/HD until I set it manually.

Try it, and see if that's the problem.

Comment: Turns out the internal bandwidth across to the WAN side of the wrt54g chokes up when the communication is non-simplex.